# How to tell on gerrit which changes were submitted together if a topic is reused?

Tags: git, jenkins, repo

Gerrit topic submissions allow you to submit a set of changes together, by labeling them with a "topic", which is identified by a string.

Once a topic is submitted and the patches merged, it's possible for that "topic" to be reused.  So for example, Patch #1 and #2 could be uploaded and merged on topic "myfeature".  Then, after they are merged, Patch #3 and #4 are uploaded on topic "myfeature".  Once patch #3 and #4 are merged, all patches #1, #2, #3, and #4 are on the topic "myfeature" and their status is "merged".  Is there any way to tell at that point that #1 and #2 were really merged separately from #3 and #4?

I found [an old thread from during the development of the topics feature for gerrit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/gXjbuhfW0tg), and it discusses a "topic id" which would be unique in this scenario, but I can't seem to find anything similar to this in the current gerrit documentation or API responses.

To give a little more context, I am trying to do this in the context of a Jenkins job launched from the Gerrit Trigger plugin.  I'm trying to find the exact set of patches which were part of the triggering topic submission.  If there is some technique that could work taking advantage of this specific context, that would work too.

Comment: Every change has a unique numeric id. So, for example, you could use the smallest or the biggest id of the changes as the topic ticket. You don't have to reuse any topic string and it's very convenient to get the id.

Comment: Yes I understand that if a topic is not reused this is no longer a problem, but gerrit provides no mechanism to enforce that.

Comment: You can check that information in the history field